# Coexistence of UCP and HTTP server on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-ucp

I have a Docker EE running on a Host with IP `172.10.100.17`. I have installed UCP using the default parameters and I have also deployed nginx container with host port 443 mapped to 443 on the container.

```
docker run -it --rm --name ucp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/ucp install --host-address 172.10.100.17 --interactive  
docker run -it -d --name ngx -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx
```

1. Can UCP and Nginx co-exist with both serving at
       `https://172.10.100.17`?
2. What is the best practice for deploying UCP when my primary goal is to have nginx/apache serving on Host IP?
3. Would it be recommended to set a static IP to nginx container/service?

(Note:https is enabled on nginx)

Comment: Can you give a link to what exactly UCP is (you've tagged it with an Oracle-related tool, which doesn't seem to match the rest of your question)?  The easy two thirds of the answer are (1) no, only one service can listen on a given host port, and (3) no, there's no particular reason to assign static IPs to containers (or really to think about the container-private IPs in most cases).

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, i have changed the tag to docker-ucp

Comment: Are you sure UCP uses port 80? This says 443 and others, but not 80: https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/admin/install/system-requirements/

Comment: @David you are right. I have updated my question. So basically my question if docker ucp and nginx both have similar configuration, How to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The key is in the -p parameter, which handles port mapping. The first port listed is on the host, and the second is in the container.](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) So -p 80:80 means to map port 80 on the host to port 80 in the container.

Let’s expand this to Nginx. I’m going to assume you want to use HTTPS with both UCP and Nginx. Only one application can listen per port on a host. So, if two containers both expose port 443, you can have one use port 443 on the host (-p 443:443) and the other use a different port (-p 4443:443). Then you’ll access them at ports 443 and 4443 on the host, respectively, even though both containers expose port 443 - Docker is doing the port forwarding.

It may be that you’re asking how to run both containers on a single port using Nginx as a reverse proxy. That’s a possibility as well, though more complex.

Comment: I guess you answered my question. I cannot have multiple containers using same port. [Reverse proxy is not what I am looking for]